# Error bars in ggpubr/ggbarplot suddenly merged (no code change), how can I separate them again?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I have the following code:

```
ggbarplot(Text1, x = "Page", y = "IA_REGRESSION_OUT_COUNT", 
          color = "Modified", add = "mean_se", fill = "Modified", 
          width = .6, position = position_dodge(0.8)) +  
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test", aes(group = Modified), 
                     label = "p.signif", label.y = 0.3, na.rm = TRUE) + 
  labs(x = "Page number", y = "Avg Regression Count", 
       caption = "* = p value < 0.5; **** = p value < 0.0001") + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "black")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#CCCCCC","#FFFFFF")) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

which produced this plot

[image: Before]

However, since today this is what comes out, maybe because some updates?

[image: After]

Any idea how to fix this and have it back with the error bars for each column?

Comment: Following [this thread](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/71), you may need to update your version of ggpubr (it looks like a new version went up on CRAN a couple of weeks ago).

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed now. Please install the latest developmental version on GitHub( https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/109) and try this:

```
library(ggpubr)
ggbarplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len", 
   add = "mean_se", 
   color = "supp", palette = "jco",
   position = position_dodge(0.8)
)
```

The generated plot should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. just add follow code.

```
add.params = list(group = "type"), position = position_dodge(0.8)
```